# How to check if the phone number is chosen from the suggestion in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, phone-number, uikeyboard

I want to check if the phone number entered in the textfield is from the suggestion or not as soon as it is entered so that i could remove the code from the phone number. how can we do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead you can check whether the number contains a '+' and you can remove it, also you can take last 10 digits as phone number.

Comment: I think that will work. But how can we get that click event. How will we know if the "user clicked on suggestion" in 'shouldChangeCharactersIn'

Answer (score -1):

using these library and functions

```
 Import ContactUI
 Import UIKit
 @IBAction func getcontact(_ sender : AnyObject) {

 }
```

and you can even say the contact using this

```
 IBAction func SayContact (_ sender : AnyObject)  {}
```

you may refer to this book 
it explain how to do that in details
when you open the link scroll down little , until you find the code where it talk about Func ShowPEoplePicker ( )

and you will get it done :)

[click here to open the book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=f812DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA380&lpg=PA380&dq=xcode%20swift%20how%20to%20display%20suggested%20contacts%20list%20on%20iphone&source=bl&ots=HDla20xlCO&sig=ACfU3U3PvVe9R9ve0JJvhlb6MHNvnqPhpQ&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqn5CD3vTiAhVioVwKHUeIAR8Q6AEwDXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=xcode%20swift%20how%20to%20display%20suggested%20contacts%20list%20on%20iphone&f=false)

Good luck